# Loading iframe in google-chrome extension (Error: Protocols must match)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, roblox

Code in manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Test",
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
      "notifications",
      "https://www.roblox.com"
  ],
  "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src https://www.roblox.com 'self' ; object-src 'self'",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "icon.png"
  ]
}
```

Code in background.js:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe")
iframe.src = "http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=1"

document.body.appendChild(iframe)
```

I keep getting  this error:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL chrome-extension://dbekkpdpdheclekbpajgigjdlpleolgd/_generated_background_page.html from frame with URL http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=1. The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'http', the frame being accessed has a protocol of 'chrome-extension'. Protocols must match.
```

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

Problem in your code is your `http://www.roblox.com/*` source is not secure. The **whitelist only secure resources** part of the Chrome error message refers to this. You have to use `https://www.roblox.com/*` and declare

> "content_security_policy": "script-src https://roblox.com 'self' ; object-src 'self'"

in manifest file. I observed your domain has is making calls through

> http://www.roblox.com/Ads/IFrameAdContent.aspx?v=2&slot=Roblox_User_Top_728x90&format=banner&v=2.

`http` URL, which is not white listed.

## References for further reading

- [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html)

Comment: @Luaox:Post your related code by editing your question, will check it.

Comment: @Luaox: When i inspected your page, there are calls still made with https protocol instead of https, this causes error. I guess you need to use secure version of domain.