# accessing an iframe's URL client-side

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension. I have a popup box that comes up when a user clicks my extension button on the right side of their chrome browser near the url bar.

The popup box contains an iFrame.

I want to get that iframe's URL client-side. Here is my attempt thus far.

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
          <body style="width:300px height:400px" >
      <iframe id="framey" frameBorder="0" src="https://localhost:5000/login" width="300" height="400">
          <body>
      </iframe>
      <script src="popup.js"></script>

      <button>Click for to get the iframe URL!</button>

    </html>
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});

function clickHandler(e) {
    var iframe_URL = document.getElementById("framey").contentWindow.location.href;
    console.log("The url is", iframe_URL);

}
```

This results in the following error

```
Uncaught Security Error: Blocked a frame with origin "chrome-extension://ldpopcacdgmhjjahdmhiongcigbpfmjm" from accessing a frame with origin "https://localhost:5000".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "chrome-extension", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: I've never tried this, but it seems like you might be able to add the url in the manifest.json file, and use [chrome.webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation). Just an initial thought — hope that helps!

Comment: can i see a code example of what you mean?

Comment: I don't really have a way to test it, was just trying to point you in the correct direction by searching for others with the same issue. Have you tried included the manifest.json file with the url you're loading in the iFrame (in this case `http://localhost:5000`)? Found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293451/loading-iframe-in-google-chrome-extension-error-protocols-must-match) as well — looks like this person is trying to do the same thing and it seems like it works, as long as the protocol matches (http/https).